# Ubuntu 15.10 Intel® 945GM x86/MMX/SSE2 graphics driver issues with 32-bit OS

Tags: 15.10, intel-graphics

I am also having issues with my graphics driver.

```
Graphics: Intel® 945GM x86/MMX/SSE2
OS type: 32-bit
```

The screen gets corrupted with lines all over it and the only way to fix it is to force a refresh by moving some windows around with the mouse. The issue started after I upgraded from 15.4 to 15.10, which appears to be how it went for Alejandro Lázaro and jit, but the solution that jit tried did not work for me; which involved  editing the following file with the contents listed:

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
EndSection
```

Comment: Please provide some more details. Linux kernel version by using command "uname -r". If the below answer works please mark it as correct.

Comment: 4.2.0-27-generic

Comment: lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 15.10
Release: 15.10
Codename: wily

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Enter Command

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

This command will create the file and open it for you. 
Insert the text below exactly as it appears and click save.

```
Section "Device" 
Identifier "Card0" 
Driver "intel" 
Option "AccelMethod" "sna" 
EndSection
```

and then

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: That gave different issues.  Menus do not display  correctly in applications, so I reverted to my previous state.

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears